# How to select records randomly from the DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following single column pandas DataFrame called `y`. The column is called `0`(zero).

y =

```
1
0
0
1
0
1
1
2
0
1
1
2
2
2
2
1
0
0
```

I want to select N row indices of records per `y` value. In the above example, there are 6 records of `0`, 7 records of `1` and 5 records of `2`.
I need to select 4 records from each of these 3 groups.

Below I provide my code. However this code always selects the **first** N (e.g. 4) records per class. I need the selection to be done **randomly** on a whole dataset.

How can I do it?

```
idx0 = []
idx1 = []
idx2 = []

for i in range(0, len(y[0])):
    if y[0].iloc[i]==0 and len(idx0)<=4:
        idx0.append(i)
    if y[0].iloc[i]==1 and len(idx1)<=4:
        idx1.append(i)
    if y[0].iloc[i]==2 and len(idx2)<=4:
        idx2.append(i)
```

**Update:**

The expected outcome is a list of indices, not the filtered DataFrame `y`.

```
n = 4
a = y.groupby(0).apply(lambda x: x.sample(n)).reset_index(1).\
    rename(columns={'level_1':'indices'}).reset_index(drop=True).groupby(0)['indices'].\
                                                    apply(list).reset_index()

class = 0
idx = a.ix[2].tolist()[class]
y.values[idx]   # THIS RETURNS WRONG WRONG CLASSES IN SOME CASES

0
1. # <- WRONG
0
0
```

Comment: Why do you need the index, more-so than the random sample?

Comment: @ALollz: I need to use it as a reference in my code.

Comment: Well yes, I just didn't know if you needed it to reindex or perform some calculation that could be done in one go with the `.sample`. Also, in the case that a group has fewer than `N` rows (say 3 in the above example), should you only get the indices of the 3, or do you want to sample with replacement up to 4 elements?

Comment: @ALollz: This problem can be ignored. N is always greater than the number of records per class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing column "y" belongs to a dataframe "df" and you want to select N=4 random rows:

```
for i in np.unique(df.y).astype(int):
    print(df.y[np.random.choice(np.where(df.y==np.unique(df.y)[i])[0],4)])
```

You will get:

```
10116    0
329      0
4709     0
5630     0
Name: y, dtype: int32
382     1
392     1
9124    1
383     1
Name: y, dtype: int32
221      2
443      2
4235     2
5322     2
Name: y, dtype: int32
```

**Edited**, to get index:

```
pd.concat([df.y[np.random.choice(np.where(df.y==np.unique(df.y)[i])[0],4)] for i in np.unique(df.y).astype(int)],axis=0)
```

You will get:

```
10116    0
329      0
4709     0
5630     0
382      1
392      1
9124     1
383      1
221      2
443      2
4235     2
5322     2
Name: y, dtype: int32
```

To get a nested list of indices:

```
[df.holiday[np.random.choice(np.where(df.holiday==np.unique(df.holiday)[i])[0],4)].index.tolist() for i in np.unique(df.holiday).astype(int)]
```

You will get:

```
[[10116,329,4709,5630],[382,392,9124,383],[221,443,4235,5322]]
```

Comment: I need to get indices.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: This code returns me a different number of records for 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: Does the column have a sufficient number of records (n>=4) for each class ?

Comment: yes, always. I need to get indices of classes separately in `idx0`, `idx1` and `idx2`,

Comment: I fixed and added time spent in computation of options.

Comment: Your last update (last line of code) is exactly what I was searching for. Thanks.

Comment: @ScalaBoy You're welcome. As an additional comment, the code I provided is more complex than pure Pandas. For a cold start, Pandas takes 0.38 sec in my dataset, and my code, 0.17 sec. After that, my code takes 0.17 sec and Pandas, 0.08 sec. If you plan to use this in a huge dataset, use multiprocessing for the loop and it will be way faster than pure Pandas.

Answer (score 4):

Use `groupby()` with [`df.sample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
n=4
df.groupby('Y').apply(lambda x: x.sample(n)).reset_index(drop=True)

    Y
0   0
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   2
9   2
10  2
11  2
```

EDIT, for index:

```
df.groupby('Y').apply(lambda x: x.sample(n)).reset_index(1).\
    rename(columns={'level_1':'indices'}).reset_index(drop=True).groupby('Y')['indices'].\
                                                    apply(list).reset_index()

   Y          indices
0  0   [4, 1, 17, 16]
1  1    [0, 6, 10, 5]
2  2  [13, 14, 7, 11]
```

Comment: I should receive the list of indices. Could you please update your solution? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I need ti get indices per classes like it's in my code: `idx0`, `idx1`, `idx2`.

Comment: @ScalaBoy check now. think it is what you wanted

Comment: It works. Thanks! To get, for example, `idx0` as numpy array, should I save the result of your code in `df2` and do `idx0 = df2.ix[0].tolist()`? How can I get such type of array idx0 = [2,3,1,5] ?

Comment: @ScalaBoy, `df2.values` you mean?

Comment: Ok, I found out how to get what I need. But I see that the results are wrong in some cases. I see that records of different classes are mixed.

Comment: Please see my update. I used your code and showed what is wrong.

Comment: @ScalaBoy i dont understand, just looked at the indices, all of which fall under the valid group. initially ihad skipped the first row so had different output, try my code on the sample you have provided now.

Comment: You are misunderstanding .iloc and .loc , this is two different things .One is for position , anther is look up index @ScalaBoy

Answer (score 4):

Using

```
idx0,idx1,idx2=[ np.random.choice(y.index.values,4,replace=False).tolist()for _, y in df.groupby('0')]
idx0
Out[48]: [1, 2, 16, 8]
```

---

To be more detail

```
s=pd.Series([1,0,1,0,2],index=[1,3,4,5,9])
idx=[1,4] # both anky and mine answer return the index
s.loc[idx] # using .loc with index is correct 
Out[59]: 
1    1
4    1
dtype: int64
s.values[idx]# using value with slice with index, is wrong
Out[60]: array([0, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: In my real dataset this solution mixes classes. When I do y.values[idx0], I see some records of classes 1, while there should be only 0 class records.

Comment: @ScalaBoy when you mention index ,you should do with .loc, not values[idx0], it should be y.loc[idx0], and this is the reason you downvote my solution ?

Comment: @ScalaBoy How about your question? if you change to .loc , return the expected output ?

Answer (score -1):

```
N = 4
y.loc[y[0]==0].sample(N)
y.loc[y[0]==1].sample(N)
y.loc[y[0]==2].sample(N)
```